# Finding a file in a Google Shared Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using a service account to access my shared drive via some python scripting.
I have a larger application where I am trying to create a new Google Sheet in a shared drive using the FolderID. But before I create it I use the Drive API to see if the sheet already exists.  I am able to write to the folder successfully.  But for some reason I cannot get drive_service.files().list to work properly.
I have broken the actions into simple individual scripts for testing.  Again I have confirmed I can write to folder.

But if I try searching by name, or I tried to make it even more simple just by listing all the files in a folder by ID, I get no files found:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'])

# Create a Google Drive API client
drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

def list_files(folder_id=None):
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents" if folder_id else "'root' in parents"
    
    results = drive_service.files().list(q=query, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    files = results.get('files', [])

    if not files:
        print("No files found.")
    else:
        print("Files:")
        for file in files:
            print(f"{file['name']} ({file['id']})")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder_id = input("Enter the folder ID (Press Enter to list the root directory): ")
    list_files(folder_id)
```

It will however list files in the root of the service account's drive.  But it can't for the folder I am specifying on the shared drive, EVEN won't list a file that the service account created in the shared drive.
The service account has "content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification? In this modification, your `list_files` function is modified.

#### Modified script:

```py
def list_files(folder_id=None):
    query = f"'{folder_id}' in parents" if folder_id else "'root' in parents"

    results = drive_service.files().list(
        q=query,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,
        corpora="allDrives"
    ).execute()
    files = results.get('files', [])

    if not files:
        print("No files found.")
    else:
        print("Files:")
        for file in files:
            print(f"{file['name']} ({file['id']})")
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your service account has permission for retrieving the file metadata from the shared Drive. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list)